# what is FROM scratch in dockerfile contains

Tags: docker

I have created an image using below

FROM scratch
CMD ["sh"]

if I am logging into the container using docker run -it imagename /bin/sh

then I am able to see /bin /dev /etc all the folders same as like normal linux installation.
That means, even scratch is also linux image layer ?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch#:~:text=FROM%20scratch,-This%20image%20is&text=You%20can%20use%20Docker's%20reserved,filesystem%20layer%20in%20your%20image.

Comment: The sequence you describe shouldn't work; the `scratch` image doesn't contain `/bin/sh` or anything else.

Answer (score 4):

[From Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch#:%7E:text=FROM%20scratch,-This%20image%20is&text=You%20can%20use%20Docker%27s%20reserved,filesystem%20layer%20in%20your%20image.),

> This image is most useful in the context of building base images (such
> as `debian` and `busybox`) or super minimal images (that contain only a
> single binary and whatever it requires, such as `hello-world`).
>
> As of Docker 1.5.0 (specifically, [docker/docker#8827](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/8827)), `FROM scratch` is
> a no-op in the `Dockerfile`, and will not create an extra layer in your
> image (so a previously 2-layer image will be a 1-layer image instead).
>
> From [https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/#creating-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch):
>
> > You can use Docker’s reserved, minimal image, `scratch`, as a starting
> > point for building containers. Using the `scratch` “image” signals to
> > the build process that you want the next command in the `Dockerfile` to
> > be the first filesystem layer in your image.
> >
> > While `scratch` appears in Docker’s repository on the hub, you can’t
> > pull it, run it, or tag any image with the name `scratch`. Instead, you
> > can refer to it in your `Dockerfile`. For example, to create a minimal
> > container using `scratch`:
>
> ```
> FROM scratch
> COPY hello / 
> CMD ["/hello"]
> ```

So, `scratch` is a "built in" base that docker uses to host any container. There is a dummy image on Docker Hub for `scratch` but you can't pull it.

`scratch` gives you an empty file system and has the ability to run statically compiled commands. That is it. `scratch` doesn't count as a layer and, on its own, does nothing.

The implementation of `scratch` comes from your installation of Docker, not from a pulled image.